# map collection of model to viewmodel with automapper

Tags: automapper

iwant to map collection of model to viewmodel with automapper
this is my code

```
public class LanguageViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Word> Categories { set; get; }
        public IList<string> PictureURL { set; get; }
    }
```

and this my model

```
public class Word : BaseFieldsTables
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("MainWord")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelationshipBetweenWords> MainWords { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("RelatedWord")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelationshipBetweenWords> RelatedWords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify desired mapping? Something like Word.Language.Name -> LanguageViewModel.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fot his example you start with top domain model and map it with inner collections called [Nested mappings](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings).

```
mapper.CreateMap<Word , LanguageViewModel>()                
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.Text));
```

For inner collections within Word domain model, you need to define separate mappings for Categories and Pictures.

```
mapper.CreateMap<Picture, PictureModel>()                
   .ForMember(dest => dest.PictureURL , src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Picture.Urltext));

mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryModel>()                
   .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryId, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Category.CategoryInt));
```

and for all remaining inner collections you need to define mapping to make it work